# How can we award a +25 bounty?

Tags: support, bounty

I have recently come across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66796407/14185615) answer which received a **+25** bounty. Is it even possible and when can we award a **+25** bounty?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't award a 25 points bounty.

But if you set a 50 points bounty, **fail to award it, and the system awards it automatically**, then it gives the winner only half the amount. E.g. 25 points.

From the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty):

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a minimum score of 2 **will be awarded half the bounty amount** (or the full amount, if the answer is also accepted)